# Excel formula to combine info on different columns

Tags: excel-formula

I need to make a spreadsheet with 4 columns and on the 1st column I need a formula to enter and combine the text of the other columns. The spreadsheet will be as follows:
In the 3rd column will contain first names and the 4th column will contain last names. The 2nd column will contain other names. If there are names in the 3rd and 4th columns the 2nd column will always be blank and if there is text in the 2nd column the 3rd and 4th will always be blank.
In the first column I need a formula that will enter and combine the information for the 2nd, 3rd and 4th column.

Comment: possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804766/how-to-combine-multiple-columns-in-excel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine multiple columns in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804766/how-to-combine-multiple-columns-in-excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can just use something like this.  Enter the following into `A2`, assuming your data begins in the second row, and that columns `A` through `D` inclusive are the first through fourth columns:

```
=IF(B2="", C2&" "&D2, B2)
```

This simple formula says to take the first and last name concatenated together should column `B` be empty.  Otherwise, it takes column `B`.